# Can we still use OLS on truncated a $Y$ if its conditional distribution is normal?

Tags: least-squares, truncation, tobit-regression

I was recently reading about Heckman selection models, and got sidetracked by how little I knew about truncated data. I was reading [these slides](http://fmwww.bc.edu/EC-C/S2013/823/EC823.S2013.nn12.slides.pdf), and on page 78 Baum mentions that if part of a sample has a truncated $Y$ variable, we can’t even use regression analysis on that $Y$ to make inferences about the sub-sample (whose $Y$ variable is truncated).

I know that having a truncated $Y$ means the distribution will be skewed, but if the conditional distribution of $Y$ is normal, can we still use basic OLS? Also, does a tobit model work on the assumption that the conditional distribution is truncated?

Comment: How would it be possible for a truncated distribution to be conditionally normal at every $X$?

Comment: Well I don't know if it is possible or not, that's why I'm asking the question. You, whuber and gung are always great for coming up with graphs that demonstrate these things! Let me expand my question. If you are looking at respondent's hours of work but you only have information on hours of work for people who are employed (hours of work for unemployed people are missing). Does the distribution of hours of work, for those who are working, count as a truncated distribution? Would it not be possible for this distribution to not be normal unconditionally but normal at every education level?

Comment: Hours of work can't be normal, since its bounded at both ends, and there are going to be strong peaks at typical work-hours. It won't even be likely to be much like a truncated-normal.

Comment: Take a skew-normal distribution, and apply the reverse of the skewing to make it normal. (See also an edit to my answer with additional explanations.)

Answer (score 4):

It's not about the distribution being skewed (in the statistical sense of having a non-zero third moment). It is about the conditional mean (given $X$) being shifted by truncation. So no, OLS is not making sense. You can still use it, but the estimates will be biased. No statistical software would spit out a diagnostic message that your sample was truncated, and that's something like metadata that comes along with the data themselves that you are bringing into data analysis.

A tobit model is one way to take truncation into account. It tends to be overly sensitive to the assumption of underlying normality, and breaks for whatever mild violations that linear regression can withstand, like heteroskedasticity. So it is a step in the right direction, but it rarely is a step that's good enough.

Motivation for Heckman comes from a counterfactual experiment of what a person's wage would be should they participate in the labor market -- what would a market pay if a housewife did not have that independently wealthy husband and have to work instead. From a finite population perspective, the distribution of observed wages is what it is -- skewed or not, lognormal, uniform, whatever -- a set of numbers. It is only truncated in the modeling sense that you don't observe the wage for everybody who is of working age and of good health (unless you are in a Communist country where everybody has to work or would go to jail if they don't... but the wage does not make an economic sense in such countries, anyway). So for Heckman model, the truncation problem is rather a missing data problem. It is mentioned as such in some [missing data books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471183865) written by pure statisticians who otherwise don't look very often into econometrics.

Comment: It's interesting that you describe the Heckman model as a missing data model. When I was reading about it, my original thoughts were that it was closer to a method such as propensity score matching (where we use the observables in the data as best as possible) than a quasi-experimental method such IV or RDD (which uses exogenous variation to identify the treatment effect). In fact, it was the idea that Heckman selection is a missing data model that got me thinking should we just use OLS for truncated data. People have always told me that if correctly specified, OLS and PSM tend to give the 1/2

Comment: 2/2 exact same answers. So I was wondering would the same apply for a tobit or heckman selection?